# Access SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can anyone help me with the syntax on the following query?

I keep getting the following error message: The Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

I've looked at it over and over and still can't find it. I need a fresh set of eyes:

```
SELECT [Locations].[Property],
  [Cores].Location, 
  [Cores].Core, 
  [Keys].Core,
  Count ([Keys].[Key Seq]) AS [CountOfKey Seq]
FROM [Cores], [Locations], [Keys]
WHERE (
   [Cores].Location = [Locations].Location
   and [Cores].Core = [Keys].Core)
   and (((Keys.[Key Seq])<>0))
GROUP BY Locations.[Property], [Cores].Location, [Cores].Core,[Keys].Core
HAVING (((Keys.Core)<>"No Lock"))
UNION SELECT  [Locations].[Property], 
   [Cores].Location, 
   [core_crosswalk].related_core as Core, 
   [Keys].[Key Seq], Count ([Keys].[Key Seq]) AS [CountOfKeySeq],
FROM   [Cores], [Locations], [Keys], [core_crosswalk]
WHERE (
   [Cores].Location = [Locations].Location,
   and [Cores].Core = [core_crosswalk].core,
   and [core_crosswalk].related_core = [Keys].Core),
   and (((Keys.[Key Seq])<>0))
GROUP BY Locations.[Property], Cores.Core
HAVING (((Keys.Core)<>"No Lock"))
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

Comment: Should there be a semicolon before the keyword UNION?

Comment: You're missing a comma: `[Keys].[Key Seq] ***,*** count ([Keys].[Key Seq]) `, but I suspect that there are SEVERAL syntax issues.  Try formatting the query better by moving each part to its own line - then perhaps the issue(s) will be more clear.

Comment: `AS ([CountOfKey Seq]) ` remove parentheses in your alias too

Comment: And *property* is a [reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE) in Access, needing escaping with square brackets or backticks.

Comment: there's another comma missing between [Locations].location and [Cores].location

Comment: the comma before ORDER BY should be removed too

Comment: Thanks all I've made all corrections. This Looks better but I'm still getting the error:

Comment: Start with basic debugging. Does the top query (before union) work when run alone? Does the bottom query work when run alone?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help very much!

Comment: When I run the top part of the query (everything above Union) I get the following error:

Your Query does not include the specified expression 'Location' as part of an aggregate function

Comment: You have to include in the GROUP BY all selected fields not in an aggregate expression or change them to WHERE on Total row of query builder and not display so just remove the location and [Key Seq] fields from the SELECT clause.

Comment: Without JOIN clause a Cartesian relation occurs - every record of each table is associated with every record of other table, this can cause slow performance. Use JOINS for the Location and Cores PK/FK fields instead of WHERE. Use query builder to help create the links for each SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT [Locations].[Property],
  [Cores].Location, 
  [Cores].Core as Core, 
  Count ([Keys].[Key Seq]) AS [CountOfKey Seq]
FROM ([Cores] INNER JOIN [Locations] ON [Cores].Location = [Locations].Location)
INNER JOIN [Keys] ON [Cores].Core = [Keys].Core
WHERE 
   (Keys.[Key Seq]<>0 AND Cores.Core<>"No Lock")
GROUP BY Locations.[Property], [Cores].Location, [Cores].Core
UNION 
SELECT  [Locations].[Property], 
   [Cores].Location, 
   [cores].Core, 
   Count ([Keys].[Key Seq]) AS [CountOfKeySeq]
FROM  ( ([Cores] INNER JOIN [Locations] ON  [Cores].Location = [Locations].Location)
INNER JOIN [core_crosswalk] ON [Cores].Core = [core_crosswalk].core)
INNER JOIN [Keys] ON [core_crosswalk].related_core = [Keys].Core 
WHERE (Keys.[Key Seq]<>0 AND Keys.Core<>"No Lock")
GROUP BY Locations.[Property], Cores.Core,[Cores].Location
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

As you can see I've changed it quite a bit, so you need to check that it is giving you what you want.  The biggest change is to use JOIN syntax instead of WHERE.  This makes the SQL far more readable, and was also the reason why I changed some of the fields - if you join on a field, it doesn't matter which table's value you take, since they are identical!

I combined the WHERE and HAVINGs together for neatness' sake, but you can separate them.

Also in a union, the types and numbers of both halves must match.  I wasn't sure about the type of [Key Seq], it sounded to me like an integer index.  If it is, then you cannot have it in the SELECT (which means it would have to be in the GROUP BY), if you want the count of [Key Seq], otherwise the count will always be 1.

Now if you split the two halves into separate queries, you will be able to view them in Access Query Design - you may find this useful, if you need to re-arrange things.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is almost it but I plan to separate the two halves now to find out where I need to rearrange. Wow I wish I were better at sql and joins. I'm going to study your post and try to learn more! Thank you

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to have been able to help.  When I was starting (many, many years ago) I found switching between Design View and SQL View in the Access Query designer really helpful in teaching me the basics of SQL.  The Designer does sometimes over-complicate things, particularly with WHERE clauses, and it sometimes builds the joins in a weird order, but in is a great learning tool.  Have fun!

Comment: Run the query and take a look at lines 1 and 2. How would I combine those 2 lines and make the Count of Key 8?

I'm going to continue to work the problem as I'm trying to learn, and this is a step in the right direction, but I've still got to combine numbers returned for each to make the count the true number. For 1DD-5 core and location 044A the Key count should be 8...6 operating and 2 submasters....

The problem I'm facing is I'm trying to set up data from a hierarchical database in a relational database, and it's giving me fits...not to mention I'm really rusty on my sql.

Comment: Sorry but I have no data!  If you posted some sample data, together with desired output, I could take a look, but it will have to be tomorrow morning as its 23.35 here and I need to sleep!

Comment: Yes unfortunately Access Query Design only works with simple queries.  That is why I suggested splitting into the two halves, to get the halves right, before putting them back together!